# Principles of D.I.Y. Minecraft microworlds

Tags: building

Lego released 4 Minecraft microworlds which more or less fit together with each other in some meaningful way.

Just to impress my boys I've been making my own worlds on 6x6 plates or wing pieces.  I've only got two sets (The Forest and the Nether) so I can't see too much of a theme between them.

If I wanted to make a really big Minecraft mini-world, what principles would I employ to construct each of the cells?

Comment: Probably could use a minecraft tag (I need +2 rep)

Comment: Have looked at all the other Minecraft instructions? That would give you ideas about how the world should look like.

Comment: Not sure that we have enough Minecraft specific questions to warrant one at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

There are two key ways these can "fit together":

1. Most obviously by size and connectors - all the worlds are built on 4 6x6 plates, and have a 1x2 with cross-hole brick at the bottom in the centre of at least two sides.
2. By theme (or in Minecraft terminology "biome") and features (forest, mountains, etc).

In terms of the four sets released, only two meet both of those:

- The Village
- The Forest (Ideas)

These both use the same shades of grey for the underground sections, and similar colours for the overground sections (greens, browns, etc.).

The other two sets represent completely different areas ("dimensions") within Minecraft accessed via special portals - there's no way to walk from a Forest biome to The End or Nether, so from a connecting point of view, neither of these really "connect" to the others.

So to create your own cells you'd want to follow the following guidelines:

1. Choose a Dimension (Overworld, Nether, End)
2. Work with 6x6 plates (or variants/multiples of)
3. Use a scale of 1x1x2/3 for most blocks (i.e. 2 stacked 1x1 plates) which can be capped with a 1x1 tile, for deep sections bricks can be used
4. Underground is typically 4 bricks tall, overground can be taller
5. Transition between biomes nicely (Forest - Beach, Forest - Jungle, etc.)